# python web scrapy of info-climat.fr

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to use Python Scrapy to download the information contained in https://www.infoclimat.fr/historic/

[Screenshots of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b2AG.jpg)

Here are the columns that I need:  Importance, Date de début, Date de fin,Type, Localisation, Description(optional).

Items.py

```
class ClimatItem(Item):
    importance = Field()
    date_start = Field()
    date_end = Field()
    type = Field()
    localisation = Field()
    description = Field()
```

However,they are not accessible via source code. It seems that they are contained in some javascript scripts, thought I don't really understand the web structure.

Can someone help me with this please? I've been working on this since several days but unable to find any solutions anywhere. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Please show us what code you have tried so far. Have a look at the guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the data is retrieved via AJAX. Since scrapy doesn't execute any javascript you need to replicate this behaviour manually.

Fortunately it can be easily replicated in this case. If you take a look at network tab in your browser's inspect tool you'll see that a GET XHR request is being made when you load the webpage:

[image]

It returns a json with all of the data that is in the table.

So to replicate this in scrapy you need to:

1. Figure out url parameters (or just copy them from your inspector).
2. Replicate request headers.

For example I got this working:

```
def parse(self, response):
    url = """https://www.infoclimat.fr/historic/getData.php?importance=&valfilter=1&operator=%3E&evalue=&duree=0&type=0&lieu=0&dh_deb=&dh_end=&mois=&year=&sEcho=2&iColumns=9&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=30&iDisplayLength=30&sSearch=&bRegex=false&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&sSearch_7=&bRegex_7=false&bSearchable_7=true&sSearch_8=&bRegex_8=false&bSearchable_8=true&iSortingCols=1&iSortCol_0=2&sSortDir_0=desc&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=true&bSortable_6=false&bSortable_7=true&bSortable_8=true&_=1501841738200"""
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }
    yield Request(url, self.parse_json, headers=headers) 

def parse_json(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    # here you can inspect json data and pick out the fields you need
```

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamic web pages you have these options:

1. Use [selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)
2. Use  [splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
3. Use [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

All of these basically call an external browser and access the browser's DOM rather than dealing with HTML only.

Comment: I'd like to add [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) to the list, probably as a preferred solution.

Comment: Added splash to the list. Thanks!